# Redirect 404 page rendering to CDN?

Tags: http-status-code-404, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, ddos

Is it possible to offload all 404 page renders to a CDN instead of an origin web server to prevent DDoS attacks? It seems like if you are getting DDoS'd and the attack is tying up compute resources by forcing your web server to render 404 pages, those renders would be better served through a CDN. Does anyone have any experience around this that they would be willing to share?

Answer (score 1):

CloudFront automatically protects against DDoS using Shield Standard.

If you'd like to prevent requests made to CloudFront from reaching your origin, a few options:

- Geographic restrictions: allow or block requests only from specific countries where you do not expect your viewers to be located. You can configure this within the CloudFront console, and there is no cost to use.
- Add AWS WAF. You can block common application-layer attacks, as well as create specific rules to block requests (for example, files ending in extensions you do not use - e.g., .php) or add rate limiting.
- Write a CloudFront Function (javascript function that executes at CloudFront's edge locations) to inspect the request and block any that do not match requests your application is capable of serving (for example, you could check that the incoming request matches one of the routes accepted by your application. If not, return a 404).

Both WAF and CloudFront Functions may add an additional cost. CloudFront has a perpetual free tier (meaning it is applied every month) that includes 1TB of data transfer out and 2 million CloudFront Function executions each month. Function executions beyond that are priced at $0.10 per 1 million invocations.
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Several examples of CloudFront Functions to get you started available here - https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions